# Android Eclipse DDMS ThreadView Threadstatus meaning

Tags: android, eclipse, java-native-interface, adt, ddms

I load the Android example NotePad and added one standard JavaThread, called *TEST1*.

When I look into the Threads of my NotePadApp (which does not execute native c/c++ code), I can observe the following:

[image]

**My question is:**

> Does the Status "**native**" really mean that there's native c/c++
>   executing in these threads or does native has no connection to c/c++
>   code and the Android NDK / JNI stuff?
>
> Would my Thread *TEST1* also get status native if I load and execute c/c++ code?